# IP-rules don't seem to be working on CentOS-6.6

Tags: centos, routing, ip, linux-networking, policy-routing

I faced a bit odd difficulty with policy-based routing on CentOS-6.6 server. I have a setup where I need to enroute all packets originated from `172.25.0.0/16` destinated to `172.24.0.0/16` and some `XXX.155.106.50` via certain gateway (`10.4.20.5`) behind a VPN-tunnel. I'm just doing what I always did.

1) I defined `zone2` table in my /etc/iproute2/rt_tables:

```
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
25      zone2
```

2) I added some rules, so here's what I get in reply to `ip rule show`:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32762:  from all to 172.25.0.0/16 lookup zone2
32763:  from 172.25.0.0/16 lookup zone2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

3) And, finally, I added some routes to the table, so in reply to `ip route show table zone2` I get the following:

```
XXX.155.106.50 via 10.4.20.5 dev tun0
172.25.64.0/24 dev cloudbr0  scope link
172.25.65.0/24 dev cloudbr0  scope link
172.24.0.0/16 via 10.4.20.5 dev tun0
```

Everything seems quite legit, right? But, alas, these rules don't seem to be working, as tcpdump shows me all packets from `172.25.0.0/16` being sent not through my tunnel, but directly.

The most funny thing: when I do something like `ping -I 172.25.65.254 XXX.155.106.50`, everything works fine and packets are being routed through the tunnel. But if the packet comes from the network (by the way, the networking interface is bridged) - all these rules seems to be ignored and packets go directly. :(

Any clues & hints will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the other end has to route those packets through tun0 also? Just a thought.

Comment: The behaviour of the other end doesn't matter at this point.

By the way, I had to solve this issue by implementing FWMARK. :)